# how to start a batch file minimized?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I start a batch file so it starts "minimized" like when you minimize internet explorer...

I am starting the batch from another batch using the start command.

```
start "batch" "batch.bat" /minimize  ? xD
```

Comment: Hint: Executing in a command prompt window a command with `/?` as parameter resulting in displaying help for this command. Try it out with `start /?` or with `cmd /?`. There is one more useful command, the command `help` listing many standard commands of Windows. `help start` does the same as `start /?`, it outputs the help for the command `start`.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use `/min`:

```
start /min file.bat
```

Else you could use some vbs to make it invisible.
 Hope that helps.